# Can Oracle's default object lock timeout be changed?

Tags: oracle, locking

```
> ALTER PACKAGE blah COMPILE;
(wait about 10 minutes)
> ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object
```

I understand why I get the timeout error (the package is in use).

Does anyone know if there's a way to change the default 10 minute wait interval?  Can this be configured at a database / session / statement level?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is a [`DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams068.htm#REFRN10267) parameter since 11gR1 :

> `DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT` specifies a time limit for how long DDL statements will wait in a DML lock queue. The default value of zero indicates a status of `NOWAIT`. The maximum value of 1,000,000 seconds will result in the DDL statement waiting forever to acquire a DML lock.

I'm not sure you can change the default timeout in the previous releases.

Comment: Thanks.  Shame it's not in 10g.

Comment: this didnt actually work for me.. have you tried this?  i did a `alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 5;`  then an `alter package xxx compile;` but still waited several minutes

Comment: @ShoeLace I think it will only change the behaviour if you wait on DML, for instance trying to drop a table while someones has an uncommited transaction on rows of this table (where the default behaviour is to raise an error immediately). It will probably not work when replacing a package currently in use (where the default behaviour is to wait until the package is not used anymore).